# Winsound python doesn't work with arrays that have been appended to

Tags: python, winsound

```py
import random
import winsound
songsArray = []
with open("test.txt") as f:    
        for line in f:
                songsArray.append(line)
songAmount = len(songsArray)        
selectedSong = songsArray[2]
print (selectedSong)

winsound.PlaySound(songsArray[2], winsound.SND_ALIAS)
```

In this code, I'm trying to append each line of a text file into an array which seems to work giving the right output if I print the position in the array but when trying to use it with `winsound` it doesn't work with any elements except the last one to be appended.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Currently, in the array, there are 3 items and when trying to play any other item except the last one it just does a beep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Python iterates through the lines in the a file, the newline characters are included in each line. There are a few ways to work with this, here is one:

```
import random
import winsound
with open("test.txt") as f:    
       songsArray = f.read().splitlines()
songAmount = len(songsArray)        
selectedSong = songsArray[2]
print (selectedSong)

winsound.PlaySound(songsArray[2], winsound.SND_ALIAS)
```

Comment: im using Visual studio code and when i used the .splitlines() attribute it says this -
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'splitlines'